# Python Request: Response.text attribute returns a template not the values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm writing a script to track a DHL package. I'm trying to parse the response object with beautiful soup and get the table of the following class attribute:

```
<table class="result-checkpoints show result-has-pieces" summary="DHL Express shipments checkpoints">
```

However, when I print the text attribute of the Response object, it shows a template like this:

```
<table class="result-checkpoints<%= results.length > 1 ? '' : ' show' %><%= hasPieces ? ' result-has-pieces' : '' %><%= hasEdd ? ' result-has-edd' : '' %>" summary="<%= messages.checkpoints.summary %>">
```

I guess that's why my script doesn't find the element? How to get the response as shown in the browser?

This is the script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class DHLTracker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.url = "http://www.dhl.com/en/express/tracking.html?AWB={}&brand=DHL"
        self.response = None
        self.status = None

    def searchStatus(self, awb):
        '''pass and awb an return the last status'''
        session = self.session
        url = self.url.format(awb)
        response = session.get(url=url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            self.response = response.text
            self.parseResponse()

    def parseResponse(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.response, "html.parser")
        table = soup.find_all(name="table", attrs={"class":"result-checkpoints show result-has-pieces"})
        print table
        #self.status = table[0].tbody.tr[0].td[2]
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dhl = DHLTracker()
    dhl.searchStatus("4364282856")
    print dhl.status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this page use ｊａｖａｓｃｒｉｐｔ　to fetch data, the raw data is in this [url](http://www.dhl.com/shipmentTracking?AWB=4364282856&countryCode=g0&languageCode=en&_=1481000240265)

```
http://www.dhl.com/shipmentTracking?AWB=4364282856&countryCode=g0&languageCode=en&_=1481000240265
```

you can just change this url's AWB to fetch all data